# How to fix compilation failure java 11 Idea

Tags: java, maven

I try to run command `mvn clean test` but always get

> Compilation failure: Compilation failure: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6
> But on my Project structure everywhere uses 11 version and I can't find where I should change my JDK version

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The java version can be specified in the `pom.xml`, is that the case in your project?

Comment: check what is in pom.xml

Comment: When you compile your code with `mvn clean test` on the command line, you're compiling your project with Maven - that has nothing to do with IntelliJ's settings.

Comment: my pom configure for compiler looks like that https://i.imgur.com/erDTL2x.png

Comment: FYI, you can compile the maven project within Intellij so it picks the JDK that you see on `Project Structure`. Look for `Maven` tab on top right corner and double click root-> Lifecycle-> compile

Comment: my maven sees different java versions on terminal and idea
idea - https://i.imgur.com/6nLloaO.png
terminal - https://i.imgur.com/sIoxhBl.png